# Solve for Variable 'g' i.e. Simplify Equation

Tags: expression

Can someone help me simplify this expression for a Civil Engineering application?  I had a quick answer here to some logical operations earlier, so I thought I would give it a try...

d=(g-h)*0.5/2*h + (g-l)*0.5/2*l + (L - (g-h)*0.5/2 - (g-l)*0.5/2) * g

where d=2.67; h=0.04; l=0.03; and L=28.4

I can't simplify the equation to isolate 'g' though I got this far

Comment: Try Wolfram Alpha (www.wolframalpha.com), using the `Solve[equation, variable]` function.

Comment: d=((g*.25) - (h*.25)) * h + ((g*.25) - (l*.25)) * l + (L - ((g*.25) - (h*.25)) - ((g*.25) - (l*.25)) ) * g
d=((g*.25) - (h*.25)) * h + ((g*.25) - (l*.25)) * l + Lg - (((g*.25) - (h*.25)) * g) - (((g*.25) - (l*.25)) * g)
d=.25gh - .25h^2   + .25gl - .25l^2   + Lg - .25g^2 -.25gh - .25g^2 -.25gl
d=-.25h^2   - .25l^2   + Lg -.25g^2  -.25g^2
...

Answer (score 3):

[Wolfram alpha has no trouble solving it.](http://tinyurl.com/3yc55jy)

g is approximately 56.7759 (assuming I substituted correctly).

Macsyma/Maxima, Maple, Mathematica, or any other CAS would also help you if you need answers and not solutions.

Comment: You are right, but there are actually two subproblems resulting from the square and I needed the other answer which was -0.093873026
...ultimately it had to do with perfect squares that popped up from the reduction to 2*(d+.25h^2)=g^2 -g2L

Answer (score 1):

In each term where you have (g-X)Y for some expressions X and Y, factor this into gY-XY. Eliminate the parentheses of the third term. Then factor out g.

Comment: I got to here: d+.25h^2 + .25l^2 = Lg -.5g^2 but I am stuck with the right side binomial I think...

Comment: You can use the quadratic formula. But it'd probably be smarter to go with Wolfram Alpha; why didn't I think of that? (In particular, a naive implementation of the quadratic formula is subject to loss of precision for certain inputs.)